# Python3: Produce a patern with stars and must use a 2 dimensional list

Tags: python-3.6

Python3.6: I have an assignment for which I need to produce a patern with stars and must use a 2 dimensional list.

The first part was merely using the print() with concatenation.
def corners():

```
"""This function will display a Stars in the top left
   and bottom right corners"""
a4 = '****'
a3 = '***'
a2 = '**'
a1 = '*'
s3 = '   '
s4 = '    '
s5 = '     '
print(a4 + s3)
print(a3 + s4)
print(a2 + s5)
print(a1 + s5 + a1)
print(s5 + a2)
print(s4 + a3)
print(s3 + a4)
```

corners()

(image displayed looks like this)

```
****   
***    
**     
*     *
     **
    ***
   ****
```

Now, the second part is to do the same thing, but use a 2 dimensional list along with loops.  I have tried, and I am stuck.  The assignment has a total of 5 different parterns.  If anyone would be so kind as to provide some assistant to figure one of them out, then the other 4 should be easier.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's begin with the concrete case that matches your original static solution. Assume user input is 7. Your task is then to print 7 lines. Each line consists of 7 characters:

- 4 stars, 3 spaces, no stars
- 3 stars, 4 spaces, no stars
- 2 stars, 5 spaces, no stars
- 1 star, 5 spaces, 1 star
- ... then the same in reverse.

So, the first element of your list is `[4,3,0]`, then `[3,4,0]` and so on.

The full 2-dimensional list will be `[[4,3,0], [3,4,0], ... etc]`

Call your list `rows`:

```
rows = [[4,3,0], [3,4,0], ... etc]
```

Now if you do this:

```
for (l_stars, spaces, r_stars) in rows:
```

the first time around, `l_stars` will be 4, `spaces` will be 3, and `r_stars` will be zero. Inside the `for` loop, print the appropriate number of stars and spaces:

```
for (l_stars, spaces, r_stars) in rows:
    print("*" * l_stars, " " * spaces, "*" * r_stars, sep="")
```

If `l_stars` has the value 4, then `"*" * l_stars` will be `"****"`, and so on. The `sep` in the `print` statement is to stop `print` putting extra spaces where the commas are.

Now you see the value of using a 2-dimensional list. Your program is reduced from 14 statements to 3 and the pattern is much easier to change. The ability to change the pattern is needed if the program is to respond to user input. I must say that makes this a very challenging task for a beginner.

In the general case your task is to print *n* lines. Each line consists of *n* characters:

- *n*-3 stars, *n*-4 spaces, no stars
- *n*-4 stars, *n*-3 spaces, no stars
- *n*-5 stars, *n*-2 spaces, no stars
- ... and so on down to
- 1 star, *n*-2 spaces, 1 star
- ... then the same in reverse.

The number of rows to print is variable: you need *n* rows. One way to do this is with a *list comprehension*. If the user's input is `n`, that will be something like

```
rows = [ [...something...] for i in range(n) ]
```

The tricky part here is that your pattern is constant in the middle:

```
*     *
```

so `rows` consists of 3 parts: top-left corner, middle, bottom-right corner, and grows or shrinks upwards and downwards from the middle. So you have to build it up as 3 parts. It's not clear from your description what you want to happen if `n` is an even number. I'll assume you want two copies of the same middle row in that case.

```
try:
    n = int(input("Enter size of pattern:"))
except:
    print("Invalid input, using 7")
    n = 7

top_left = [[n-i, i, 0] for i in range (3,n-1)]
middle = [[1,n-2,1]]
if not n % 2:   # n is even, need two copies
    middle *= 2
bottom_right = [[0, i, n-i] for i in range (n-2,2,-1)]

rows = top_left + middle + bottom_right

for (l_stars, spaces, r_stars) in rows:
        print("*" * l_stars, " " * spaces, "*" * r_stars, sep="")
```

I'll leave it up to you to do any range checking on the input that is required.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.  I realize that I omitted an important part of the puzzle.  The second part, the user must enter a number bertween (5 to 4) which defines the overall dimension of the image to be displayed.

Comment: I don't understand what that program should do in response to the input. Taking what the program does now, what input number does that correspond to? It might be 5 (maximum number of stars) or 7 (length of line/number of rows) or something else.

Comment: For example:  Lets assuming a user enters the number 5, the image selected needs to adjust to the this new definition of 5 rows by 5 columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I do agree it is a challenging task for a beginner.  I will use this to help me build the other 4 patterns.  Would you like me to post the code for the other 4 patterns once I am done?

Comment: @SHQC: If you think that might be helpful to others reading this post.